# Limit Sum Value of Multiple Input Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help with javascript or jQuery.

I have three (3) input fields that I want to filter (sum of three fields).

the total value of 3 input fields is must 100. If the user fills more than 100, it will be automatically change the value that the total is 100.

you can see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/D5F3p/)

```
<input type="text" name="text1" size="3"> text1<br />
<input type="text" name="text2" size="3"> text2<br />
<input type="text" name="text3" size="3"> text3<br />

    <p>The maximum value of total 3 fields above is 100.</p>
    <pre>example 1 :

    text1 : 20;
    text2 : 30;
    text3 : 50; (will automatically filled with 50 because the total value must 100)</pre>
    <pre>example 2 :

    text1 : 37;
    text2 : 60;
    text3 :  3; (will automatically filled with 3 because the total value must 100)</pre>
```

Thanks for helping me,
I need it :)

Comment: Add the code from fiddle too!

Comment: First give it your best shot and we'll help you correct problems you run into.

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: @PalashMondal, I don't know how to build it, I've search for this case another place, but I didn't found the similar case.

Comment: @hjpotter92, hey thanks for editing. I'm new here, this is my first post. Sorry about that :)

Comment: what if sum of text1 and text2 exceeds 100, are you allowing negative value in text3 or adjusting values in text 1 & 2?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar, if sum of text1 and text2 exceeds 100, then I can't fill the value in text3.

Comment: @Imam, check my posted answer. Is this what your requiment? Here i am checking text1 if it exceeds 100 then adjusting its value to 100 and disabling other two text. if not then checking text2 and if it exceeds 100 then adjusting its value and disabling text3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $(function(){

$('input[name="text1"]').keyup(function(){

    var text1Value = $('input[name="text1"]').val();
    if(text1Value >=100)
    {
     $('input[name="text1"]').val(100);
     $('input[name="text2"]').val('');
     $('input[name="text3"]').val('');
     $('input[name="text2"]').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
     $('input[name="text3"]').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
    }
    else
    {
     $('input[name="text2"]').removeAttr('disabled'); 
     $('input[name="text3"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
$('input[name="text2"]').keyup(function(){
    var text1Value = parseInt($('input[name="text1"]').val());
    var text2Value = parseInt($('input[name="text2"]').val());
    if(isNaN(text1Value))
    {
     text1Value =0;
    }

    if(isNaN(text2Value))
    {
     text2Value =0;
    }
    var total = text1Value + text2Value;

    if(total >=100)
    {
     $('input[name="text2"]').val(100-text1Value);
     $('input[name="text3"]').val('');
     $('input[name="text3"]').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
    }
    else
    {
     $('input[name="text3"]').removeAttr('disabled');
     $('input[name="text3"]').val(100-total);
    }
});

});
```

I am checking if sum of all text boxes if exceeding 100, then making correction in the last entered textbox with disabling the next textbox.

Comment: I've test it, and I still can input > 100 in first field... http://jsfiddle.net/D5F3p/7/

Comment: I tried to access your fiddle link but not able to, hence i have changed the blur event to keydown event,please try now

Comment: try it > http://jsfiddle.net/D5F3p/8/, I still can input more than "100" on first field... I don't know why...

Comment: Thanks for the code, I will change the algorithm from your code. Thanks again Bhushan :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input:lt(2)").on("change", function() {
    var other = $("input:lt(2)").not(this).val();
    if (other.length)
        $("input:eq(2)").val(100 - this.value - other);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/D5F3p/3/

Comment: @ImamHerlambang *it's not working*. Very descriptive... yeah!

Comment: sorry, but really the code isn't working... I've check on jsfiddle too. maybe you can show how to implement that code? I'm newbie here... thanks

Comment: hey, it's working. Thanks... so sorry, but I when I try to input "100" in first input, the second and the third input still can be filled. any other ways to fix it?

Comment: @ImamHerlambang Check with `if (+this.value === 100)` and do what you need, e.g. either disable another field with `.prop("disabled", true)`, or reset the value of the current field.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest thing I can think of!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="text2"]').blur(function(){
        $('input[name="text3"]').val(100 - $('input[name="text1"]').val() - $('input[name="text2"]').val());
    });
});
```

IMO, you can do these:

1. Give only two characters for both the inputs. Don't allow more than that!
2. You also need to check if the sum of the two inputs should not exceed 101!
3. Keep the input 2 readonly, until something has been entered in input 1.
4. Keep the input 3 always readonly.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/D5F3p/5/

Comment: I've do 2nd test, and that's working. I just wondering if the first input value is "100", the other value is become "0". Can you do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check() {
    var sum = 0;
    var inputs = $(".test");
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].value == parseInt(inputs[i].value)) {
            sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
            if (sum > 100) {
                sum -= parseInt(inputs[i].value);
                inputs[i].value =  100-sum;

             }
         }
    }

 }



</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" onkeyup="check()" class="test" size="3"> 
<input type="text" onkeyup="check()" class="test" size="3">
<input type="text" onkeyup="check()" class="test" size="3">
```